# Getting error while display data from one form to another form

Tags: datagridview, combobox

I am getting an error while displaying data from one forms datagridview to another form textbox and combobox field. The image of error is attached below

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Public connection As SqlConnection
    Public connectionstring As String
    Public sqlinsertcommand As SqlCommand
    Public sqlviewrecord As SqlDataReader
    Public msg As Integer
    Public i, a As Integer
    Public id As Integer
    Public sql As String
    Public Sub databaseconnection()
        connectionstring = "Data Source=DESKTOP-H3IIA1D; Initial catalog=BBSRS; Integrated Security=True"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        connection.Open()
    End Sub
    Public Sub connectionclose()
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to add all relevant source code to you question, not only some parts and the other parts in a screenshot. This will help the other readers to understand the question.